# Setting dataSource error with Koloda view library

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a library KolodaView: https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

I got error when trying to set the `dataSource` method for my `StudyViewController`,

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import Koloda

class StudyViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var kolodaView: KolodaView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    kolodaView.dataSource = self // Error here
    kolodaView.delegate = self

}
}

extension StudyViewController: KolodaViewDelegate {
}

extension StudyViewController: KolodaViewDataSource {

func kolodaNumberOfCards(koloda:KolodaView) -> UInt {
    return UInt(5)
}

func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIView {
    return UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Image"))
}

func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardOverlayAtIndex index: UInt) -> OverlayView? {
    print(NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("OverlayView",
        owner: self, options: nil)[0])
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("OverlayView",owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? OverlayView
}
}
```

> The error message is: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: what is error message?

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: kolodaView outlet is connected properly?

Comment: ________yes________

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your error and solve it.

It seems like you are using the storyboard but you didn't set the class of your Koloda view. That means it will be nil when you are trying to set the delegate.

All you need to do is set the class to "KolodaView" as in this image:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, it is the case :D